# Migrating from Subversion to Git, but with a conversion in between

Tags: git, github, svn, command-line-interface

I have a Subversion repository with legacy code files which are binary-based.  Meaning, they can only be seen/edited with its legacy editor.  Fortunately, the editor has an export-to-text option which can be used from the command-line.

I would like to commit the text-exported code to a Git repository, but including its history (commit date, description, committer, etc).
I know there are instructions for converting from Subversion to Git, but I do not see if my wish is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most convert-X-to-Git programs these days produce data that is to be fed to `git fast-import`. This data is deliberately somewhat simple and hence easily machine-digested, and you can write your own program to digest it, modify it, and spit out updated fast-import data. By doing this you could convert the binary to text during the conversion. If that's technically difficult for any particular reason, though, you can always use a two-step approach: first convert to Git, then filter the Git repository to produce a replacement Git repository.

Comment: Very interesting,
but will the commit meta-info (date, author, etc.) remain?

Comment: The meta-info is in text form in the fast-import data. It will be clear and obvious to you and you can make any changes you like to it, or preserve it. (When using git filter-branch or git filter-repo to do an ex-post-facto edit of a repository, those programs by default also preserve metadata, and give you a chance to change the metadata, but it's often not so clear.)